# How to check AWS IoT Device connection status on the web console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I just started playing with AWS IoT. I created a thing and use mqtt-spy to connect to AWS server. All is ok.

Now I'd like to check the status of each thing in the web console, however I couldn't find such useful info near the device.

Answer (score 11):

By enabling [AWS IoT Fleet Indexing Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/iot/latest/developerguide/managing-index.html), you can get the connectivity status of a thing. Also, you can query for currently connected/disconnected devices.

First, you have to enable indexing (thingConnectivityIndexingMode) by aws-cli or through the console.

```
aws iot update-indexing-configuration --thing-indexing-configuration thingIndexingMode=REGISTRY_AND_SHADOW,thingConnectivityIndexingMode=STATUS
```

Then you can query a thing's connectivity status like the following

```
aws iot search-index --index-name "AWS_Things" --query-string "thingName:mything1"
{  
    "things":[{  
         "thingName":"mything1",
         "thingGroupNames":[  
            "mygroup1"
         ],
         "thingId":"a4b9f759-b0f2-4857-8a4b-967745ed9f4e",
         "attributes":{  
            "attribute1":"abc"
         },
         "connectivity": { 
            "connected":false,
            "timestamp":1641508937
         }         
    }
}
```

> Note: Fleet Indexing Service index connectivity data with device lifecycle events ($aws/events/presence/connected/). In some cases it may take a minute or so for the service to update indexing after a connect or disconnect event occurs.

EDIT: The javascript version of this:

```
var iot = new AWS.Iot({
    apiVersion: "2015-05-28"
});
...
var params = {
    queryString: "thingName:" + data.Item.thingName, // using result from DynamoDB
    indexName: 'AWS_Things'
    //   maxResults: 'NUMBER_VALUE',
    //   nextToken: 'STRING_VALUE',
    //   queryVersion: 'STRING_VALUE'
};

iot.searchIndex(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error from iot.searchIndex");
        console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    } else {
        console.log("success from iot.searchIndex");
        console.log(data.things[0].connectivity.connected); // t/f
    }
});
```

Comment: I followed the advice of AWS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html

I created and Delay Queue and queued up all the life cycle disconnect events. After 5 seconds I first check  the ThingIndex if the device is really offline before I take further actions. BUT if the ThingIndex takes up to one minute to update how should I take this as source of truth for the connection status? I will get stale data. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You need to subscribe to the topic on the aws iot console , test section on the right corner of AWS IoT-core. for example you to subscribe to this topic replace your client with the . 
    `$aws/events/presence/connected/<Your_clientId>`
if you have more than one thing then you have to subscribe using your ClientID
for reference check this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html

Comment: In this case I will receive connection/disconnection *events*. What about if I log in the console and need to know the current status of a thing? I expected a green/red icon that showed the current connection status. If I subscribe to events topic, I *will* receive events, but I'm in doubt about the current status.

Comment: no there is nothing like green/red icon which show the status of the IoT things that are connected. you can just subscribe the connected/disconnect that let you know whether your thing is disconnected or connected.

Comment: Green/red icon was just an example. I'm not really interested in this exact thing.
I explain better. At certain moment I open my AWS IOT console. How could I know what are the things connected in that moment? I could subscribe to life cycle events topic, but I *will* receive connected/disconnected events. I want to know if one a thing is connected *now* (through a red/green icon or a simple text string CONNECTED/DISCONNECTED).

Comment: yup, i got your point, you can have look and activity that help to let you know the activity so example https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMKi7.png please have a look over it

Comment: Do you know why this page is blank on my thing? Does that work only if I use Device Shadow, that I'm not using yet?

Comment: yes for that you have to create a group and include your thing in the group and you have to use the device shadow to know the device status. and there is nothing like that or similar what you are finding for in aws iot.